# How to determine the correct integrals

Tags: calculus, probability, learning

Suppose you are given the following joint probability distribution

$ f(x,z) = (8x^2z + z^2) \text{ where } 1 \leq x \leq 2, 1 \leq z \leq 2 $

and you what to find $P(X + Z > 2.5)$. How do you determine the integral values you need when you compute this? I am trying to solve a problem similar to this, but I'm just not sure what the correct integral values would be. In this example I think x would be from 1.5 to 2 and z would be from 2.5-x to 2, but is this the right idea?

Comment: **Warning:** That $f(x,z)$ is not a probability density function.  Check for typos.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to draw it out. **Always draw out the graph.** Instead of $X,Z$, think of $X,Y$ (easier to visualize)

We have $X+Y > 2.5$ which means $Y>2.5-X$.

We also have that the range is $1\leq x \leq 2, 1\leq y \leq 2$

First task is to draw the region bounded by $x,y$, and then draw your probability function and see where they intersect. In this case it is the yellow region.

[image]

In this case it might help to break the integral in two, as I have shown in black.

So your integrals could be:

$$\int_{1}^{2}\int^{2.5-x}_{1}dydx+\int_{1}^{2}\int^{2}_{1.5}dydx$$

Comment: Splitting along the horizontal, would give: $$\int_1^{1.5}\int_{2.5-y}^2 f(x,y)~dxdy+\int_{1.5}^2\int_1^2 f(x,y)~dxdy$$

Comment: THanks @GrahamKemp for showing the other way

Answer (score 1):

> and you what to find P(X+Z>2.5). How do you determine the integral values you need when you compute this?

You need to integrate f(x,z) over the intersection of the support and the criteria: $$\{(x,z): 1{\leqslant}x{\leqslant}2, 1{\leqslant}z{\leqslant}2, x{+}z{>}2.5\}\\[2ex]\text{also writen as}\\[1ex]\{(x,z): 1{\leqslant}x{\leqslant}2, \max(1,2.5{-}x){<}z{\leqslant}2\}$$ This can be split into the union: $$\{(x,z):1{\leqslant}x{<}1.5,2.5{-}x{<}z{\leqslant}2\}\cup\{(x,z):1.5{\leqslant}x{\leqslant}2, 1{<}z{\leqslant}2\}$$

So thus

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Z>2.5)&=\int_{1\leqslant x\leqslant 2, \max(1,2.5-x)<z\leqslant 2} f(x,z)~\mathrm d(x,z) \\[1ex]&= \int_{(1\leqslant x<1.5, 2.5-x<z\leqslant 2)\vee(1.5\leqslant x\leqslant 2, 1<z\leqslant 2)} f(x,z)~\mathsf d(x,z)\\[1ex] &=\int_1^{1.5}\int_{2.5-x}^2 f(x,z)~\mathrm dz~\mathrm dx+\int_{1.5}^2\int_1^2f(x,z)~\mathrm dz~\mathrm dx\end{align}$$